# For-loop has Unexpected Side-Effect

Tags: c#, .net, loops, debugging

So I have been writing a small byte cipher in C#, and everything was going well until I tried to do some for loops to test runtime performance. This is where things started to get really weird. Allow me to show you, instead of trying to explain it:

First off, here is the working code (for loops commented out):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DreamforceFramework.Framework.Cryptography;

namespace TestingApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string myData = "This is a test.";
            byte[] myDataEncrypted;
            string myDecryptedData = null;
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            Console.WriteLine("Warming up for Encryption...");
            //for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            //{
            //    // Warm up the algorithm for a proper speed benchmark.
            //    myDataEncrypted = DreamforceByteCipher.Encrypt(myData, "Dreamforce");
            //}
            watch.Start();
            myDataEncrypted = DreamforceByteCipher.Encrypt(myData, "Dreamforce");
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption Time: " + watch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine("Warming up for Decryption...");
            //for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            //{
            //    // Warm up the algorithm for a proper speed benchmark.
            //    myDecryptedData = DreamforceByteCipher.Decrypt(myDataEncrypted, "Dreamforce");
            //}
            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            myDecryptedData = DreamforceByteCipher.Decrypt(myDataEncrypted, "Dreamforce");
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Decryption Time: " + watch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine(myDecryptedData);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

and my ByteCipher(I highly simplified it after the error originally occurred as an attempt to pinpoint the problem):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using DreamforceFramework.Framework.Utilities;

namespace DreamforceFramework.Framework.Cryptography
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DreamforceByteCipher
    /// Gordon Kyle Wallace, "Krythic"
    /// Copyright (C) 2015 Gordon Kyle Wallace, "Krythic" - All Rights Reserved
    /// </summary>
    public static class DreamforceByteCipher
    {

        public static byte[] Encrypt(string data, string password)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            string passwordHash = DreamforceHashing.GenerateSHA256(password);
            byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordHash);
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            bool twistPath = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                int shift = hashedPasswordBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
                bytes[i] = twistPath
                    ? (byte)(
                        (data[i] + (shift * i)))
                    : (byte)(
                        (data[i] - (shift * i)));
                passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % 64;
                twistPath = !twistPath;
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts a byte array back into a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Decrypt(byte[] data, string password)
        {
            string passwordHash = DreamforceHashing.GenerateSHA256(password);
            byte[] hashedPasswordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordHash);
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            bool twistPath = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                int shift = hashedPasswordBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
                data[i] = twistPath
                    ? (byte)(
                        (data[i] - (shift * i)))
                    : (byte)(
                        (data[i] + (shift * i)));
                passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % 64;
                twistPath = !twistPath;
            }
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }
    }
}
```

With the for loops commented out, this is the output that I get:

[image]

The very last line shows that everything was decrypted successfully.

Now...this is where things get weird. If you uncomment the for loops, and run the program, this is the output:

[image]

The decryption did not work. This makes absolutely no sense, because the variable holding the decrypted data should be rewritten each and every time. Did I encounter a bug in C#/.NET that is causing this strange behavior?

***A simple solution:***
http://pastebin.com/M3xa9yQK

Comment: In `public static string Decrypt` you change `data`. Arrays are passed by reference, so the next call to `Decrypt` is doing to receive the modified `data`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It does always give the same result.

Comment: @GSerg Nit: Arrays/objects are passed by *reference-value* (or "call by value [of the reference]") making for Call by Object Sharing semantics.

Comment: Krythic, I hope it is clear to you that if you had just asked "where in my code is my bug?" your question would not have been downvoted.  Perhaps it could have even been upvoted.

Comment: And your `Encrypt` method converts the `data` string to `bytes`, but then still uses the characters from `data` instead of the bytes from `bytes`. This is wrong if you have characters encoded as several bytes (as for Chinese characters for instance).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You're right. I should mention that I coded most of this while slightly intoxicated.

Comment: Please don't take it too personally when you are downvoted. We want SO to be a place with high quality questions and answers useful everyone who is looking for answers, as a kind of database. If you have been downvoted, you can still edit your question (or answer) and have the chance to be upvoted again.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Suggest a new title and I will gladly change it.

Comment: Maybe "For-loop has unexpected side-effect". And also ask "where is the bug?" instead of suspecting a bug in C# or .NET.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `Decrypt` method modifies the `data` input array in place. Therefore, you can only call `Decrypt` a single time with any given input byte array before the data is no longer encrypted. Take a simple console application for example:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new byte[] { 10 };
        Console.WriteLine(arr[0]); // prints 10
        DoSomething(arr);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[0]); // prints 11
    }

    private static void DoSomething(byte[] arr)
    {
        arr[0] = 11;
    }
}
```

So, to answer your question, no. You haven't found a bug in .NET. You've found a very simple bug in your code.

Comment: This was it. A minor oversight on my behalf. Thanks.